# How to update Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 on rpi4

Tags: 20.04, 64-bit, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 server 64bit on rpi4, and then have installed Ubuntu-desktop on top of it.

There are some problems on the configuration panel and sometimes WiFi is lost until reboot and there is no 3D acceleration.

Now **Ubuntu Dektop 20.10 official release** is out for rpi4.

Can I update my rpi4 but without installing 20.10? I like to remain on stable long term support release 20.04!

Will backports fix some of the issues?
Do I have to do something before?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Do you actually want to update to 20.10 or not? That's unclear - or do you need advice whether to update to 20.10 or not - because that's highly subjective (and most likely off-topic).

Comment: Anyway, updating to 20.10 *may* fix some of your issues, or it may not. And likewise, if staying on 20.04, some fixes may be introduced. But I don't think anyone here has a crystal ball to see it. However, I get the impression that 20.10 was optimized for Pi4, so maybe that is a good reason to update.

Comment: I will stay on 20.04 but I suppose that on 20.10 some  advanced  behaviour and bug fix are applied, so I like to integrate on my  installation

Comment: I'm not sure that's really possible - you'll have to choose either 20.04 or 20.10, to my knowledge. And maybe there will be additional fixes for 20.04, but again I'm not sure.